# Layout issue for messaging app Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to create a messaging app in android and have created a custom list adapter that displays the message text and then the date as well. I have got them both displaying, now want them to be able to be displayed in a certain way. I want to be able to have sent messages on one side of the screen but received messages on the other, with the date appearing below/to the side of the message text

This is the custom xml I have used for each item on the list, any ideas on how to make them wrap appropriately and move to sides of the screen would be appreciated!

(Note: I've tried using LinearLayouts with weights and RelativeLayouts with android:layout_alignParentRight and things, but couldn't get it exactly how I wanted it so thought I'd ask here!)

(Don't think other code snippets are needed but can provide if wanted!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:id="@+id/msgTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/msgDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers

Comment: find out the items that are sent and recieved, then make textview of fixed width (say 100dp) and align left/right according to sent/recieved messages.

Comment: RelativeLayout is perfect for this, using alignParentLeft or alightParentRight.  You can set this in code as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried using LinearLayouts with weights

Whats wrong with that? `android:layout_weight="0.4"`

try to use not 'fill_parent', use 'match_parent';

also, replace this

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```

to this:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, will make those changes.
But the problem i had with layout_weight is that it just makes it take up a proportion of the screen (0.4 / weight sum) rather than moving it from side to side, thanks anyway